# Is it possible to know which CSS style/attrib overrides another?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm in the Chrome Element Inspector. I know that when a CSS attribute is overriden it appears with a line-through, however is it possible to see which why it was overriden?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a matter of DOM inheritance level, a style will always apply to it's deepest child element in which it is set. For example.

```
<div style="background='#fff'">
    <div style="background='000'">
        000 takes precedence
    </div>
</div>
```

So the "why" in this matter would be that an element further up the tree is overriding it. This concept applies to stylesheets as much as the inline example I posted.

I should note a caveat - styles flagged with the **!important** tag will take precedence over other styles.

Comment: Ok, so in the Inspector it's from up to down the list... I don't know why here the title's font-weight is replaced http://prntscr.com/2s3g5m/direct

Comment: `.gm-style .gm-style-iw div` has two classnames and a tagname, while the other selector has one less classname so it is less specific. [Read more](http://designshack.net/articles/css/what-the-heck-is-css-specificity/) about this, it's important so you avoid `!important`.

Comment: "font-weight: bold" is being overridden by "font-weight: 300" setting from the parent div, which may mean in the actual stylesheet an !important setting has been included. If you want that specific div to be bold, add a new definition for "mapp-title" in your stylesheets and that should win out (and add !important if need be)